# Where to publish expository mathematics/personal notes?

Tags: soft-question, publishing

I have a short expository paper that is more or less my personal take/exploration of a topic that interests me. I submitted to Mathematics Magazine and it was rejected for non-mathematical reasons - the reviewer certified that all the math was correct, but felt that my personal exposition simply wasn't different enough from existing sources to merit publishing.

The reviewer does make a valid point that I am not introducing new material, however, I have spent a great deal of time and effort to organize the presentation in a way that (in my opinion) streamlines and motivates the truly central concepts in a way that is both accessible and exciting to a wide mathematical audience.

**My question is the following:** Do there exist similar journals to Mathematics Magazine (peer-reviewed or not) where I might consider trying to publish?

I would like to avoid simply posting on my website or on arXiv (would the latter even be appropriate?). However, I am not opposed at all to online journals.

I have also looked into the other MAA publications like the College Mathematics Journal and Math Horizons, and I feel that neither of these is appropriate for my paper. Additionally, I've looked into Mathematical Intelligencer, and this too seems not to be quite the outlet I'm looking for.

**Edit:** I have become aware of the journal Elemente der Mathematik (http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/journal.php?jrn=em). Does anyone know much about this journal? Might it be suitable for my purposes?

Comment: L’Enseignement Mathématique? Its standards are high though (I think). Also, the Milan Journal of Mathematics, but in that case too the standards might be high for your purpose. I guess you are aware of American Mathematical Monthly.

Comment: See also this MO post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15366/which-journals-publish-expository-work/211228#211228

Comment: That question is hard to answer without seeing the paper. Consider asking some professors/friends to read it and make suggestions. Post on arXiv and your website with a preamble asking for suggestions for a "real" journal. Consider giving it as a talk at a general session at an MAA or AMS meeting and asking the audience for feedback on publication. I like to read such essays if they are well done.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments! @the_fox I am aware of the Monthly, and its standards are certainly too high for my article.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker I have taken some of your suggestions, but many of my professors (I am a phd student) are more focused on research and aren't aware of many expository outlets. I will certainly consider giving my paper as talk though!

Comment: @JWP_HTX I am a Ph.D student as well. I write a expository short paper for a specific problem and I have tried to publish on three different journals (including AMM), though all of them reject my paper.  I feel that the so-called *Graduate Journal of Mathematics* also holds a high standard (because my paper got rejected from GJM as well). I am now submitting this paper to *Math Horizons*. Wish we all have good luck this time!